# Automatically fill and array with a loop without a prompt..

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I was wondering if it's possible to use a loop to fill and array without prompting the user for input? 
I have to design a program to fill an array of size 6 with multiples of 7. The specification doesn't say anything about prompting the user, and it says 'Use a loop to fill the array' so I can't hard code the numbers in. 
Of the multiples of 7 , I need to print out which ones can be divided by 3 exactly.

Is it possible to fill the array without an input from the user?
My code is below...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
 * Date: 26/02/2015
 * Time: 15:25
 * UPDATE COMMENT ABOUT PROGRAM HERE
 */
public class Array7Mult
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      int multipleSeven [] = new int[6];
      final int HOWMANY=6,DIVIDE=3;
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


      for(int count=0;count<HOWMANY;count++)
      {
         System.out.println("Please enter a multiple of 7 below..");
         multipleSeven[count]=keyboard.nextInt();
      }//for


      System.out.println("The multiples of seven that can be divided by 3 are..");

      for(int count=0;count<HOWMANY;count++)
      {

         if (multipleSeven[count] % DIVIDE == 0)
         {

            System.out.println(multipleSeven[count]);
         }//if
      }//for

   }//main
}//class
```

Comment: Why do you need a user input to populate an array? Just use a loop to populate each element in the array with something like: multipleSeven[count]=count*7;

Comment: `int multipleSeven []` is [discoraged](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) use `int[] multipleSeven` for the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Yes ofcourse. Say you want to populate an array by a variable which is incremented by one per index. Say variable `i` (so we use the same variable that's instantiated in the loop).

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    arr[i] = i;
```

Simple as that. You may ofcourse create a global variable and add it into the array within the boundaries of the loop and manipulate its value within the loop too.

```
int a = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     arr[i] = a;
     a += 10;
}
```

If you want to increment the value as a multiple of seven, you can simple use the first example and instead of doing `arr[i] = i` do `arr[i] = i*7`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
for(int count=0;count<HOWMANY;count++)
    multipleSeven[i]=(i+1)*7;
```

Instead of

```
for(int count=0;count<HOWMANY;count++)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter a multiple of 7 below..");
    multipleSeven[count]=keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

To fill the array `multipleSeven` with values `7,14,21,28,35,42`.